# GitHub Gist without line numbers?

Tags: github, jekyll, gist

GitHub Gists like [this](https://gist.github.com/anilkeshwani/60567eaa5fb8c36398c52022afbde22e#file-download_miniconda-sh) can be embedded into websites, for example [here](https://anilkeshwani.github.io/2022/10/05/conda-a-tour.html#getting-miniconda).

The default behavior displays line numbers.

[image: Gist displayed inline with line numbers]

Can Gists be embedded without line numbers displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Gist are inserted via JS and not code blocks anymore, the options described in the web for code blocks, such as the [data-gist-hide-line-numbers](https://gist.github.com/bvanderhoof/ec8cc541c45705a34988c68225627ecb) solution, do not work anymore.

Here's a "hack" that modifies the CSS of the gist:

```css
.js-line-number {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://gist.github.com/anilkeshwani/60567eaa5fb8c36398c52022afbde22e.js"></script>
```